# An indicator in the search results for having already answered/voted on a question/answer

Tags: discussion

Is it a good idea to have an sort of symbol next to the questions in the search results indicating whether one has answered/voted on it? I find myself opening the same question more than once on the sci-fi site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well aside from just remembering the titles of questions you've already looked at, the color of the link also changes when you've already visited it before.

I don't think a lot of people will be in favor of additional icons spamming the questions list just because they voted on something, especially those who try and make it a habit to vote on almost everything.

Comment: Ah. I missed that I think. Thanks!

Comment: The different color bit just works for the current session though.

Comment: What browser do you use? I use Chrome and it remembers visited links. Do you possibly clear your browsing history when closing the browser or something?

Comment: You're right. It works using Chrome!